# Remove everything that doesn't begin with pattern in R

Tags: r, regex

I have vector `myvec`. I would like to edit the values in the vector so that anything that doesn't begin with `"NAC"`, I want to delete them in addition to stuffs after `"_"`.

`myvec = c("NAC1001_09ADAA", "TI09AA_NAC02111", "NACT10099_099AD")`

Result I want:

`NAC1001, NAC02111, NACT10099`

What do I need to do for this?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(myvec, '(?<=\\b|_)NACT?\\d+')
#[1] "NAC1001"   "NAC02111"  "NACT10099"
```

---

Or with `sub` from `base R`

```
sub(".*(NACT?\\d+).*", "\\1", myvec)
```

Comment: Not sure why I am getting all NAs. I am trying to change the values of dataframe column.

Comment: @New_to_R what is the column name and object name

Comment: Column and object: `covarNHW_ADC2$IID` . BTW, sub works for me.

Comment: @New_to_R in that case, it would be `str_extract(covarNHW_ADC2$IID, '(?<=\\b|_)NACT?\\d+')`

Comment: No. That also did not work. Only sub works for me.

Comment: @New_to_R that is strange.  Can you show the `dput` of the small example for testing

Answer (score 0):

Split on underscore "_", then keep the one that starts with "N":

```
sapply(strsplit(myvec, "_"), function(i) i[ startsWith(i, "N") ])
# [1] "NAC1001"   "NAC02111"  "NACT10099"
```